# Psycopg2: connection not committing when exiting 'with' statement containing a try/except

Tags: python, python-2.7, psycopg2

First I'd like to state I'm well aware that psycopg opens a transaction that requires to be committed for a database update to occur.

However here is a quote for the documentation regarding commit:

> commit()
>
> > Commit any pending transaction to the database.
> >
> > By default, Psycopg opens a transaction before executing the first command: if commit() is not called, the effect of any data manipulation will be lost.
> >
> > The connection can be also set in “autocommit” mode: no transaction is automatically open, commands have immediate effect. See Transactions control for details.
> >
> > **Changed in version 2.5: if the connection is used in a with statement, the method is automatically called if no exception is raised in the with block.**

And similarly for rollback :

> rollback()
>
> > Roll back to the start of any pending transaction. Closing a connection without committing the changes first will cause an implicit rollback to be performed.
> >
> > **Changed in version 2.5: if the connection is used in a with statement, the method is automatically called if an exception is raised in the with block.**

However this doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe I'm being picky and and should always take the habit of explicitly committing (but it would be nice to know that a rollback will occur if I forget it for example). I was wondering if someone came up with the same issue or if I'm using my with statement incorrectly.

Here is what my code looks like :

```
import psycopg2
from contextlib import closing

with closing(psycopg2.connect(
                               #conn params
                              ) as conn, \
     closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:

     try:
         sql = #query
         cur.execute(sql)

         output = cur.statusmessage
         print output

     except Exception, e :
         print "Error message : {}".format(e)
         raise
```

This doesn't work. There is no problem with the query itself since I get :
    UPDATE 842518
as output as expected. However the changes from the connection are clearly not committed since my db isn't updated.
If I add

```
conn.commit()
```

in the try statement it works but the whole point is to avoid doing so.

My psycopg2 version is 2.6.

[Link to doc](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit)

Comment: Just a hunch, but wrapping the connection and cursor objects in `closing` is prolly messing with their context handling; they are context managers them selves. A `closing` wrapper will just call their `close()` methods on exit.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Tried removing the `closing` and it works indeed. Although now I feel like I should manually call `conn.close()` and `cur.close()`. Feel free to post your comment as an answer which I will accept

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrapping the connection and cursor objects in closing is prolly messing with their context handling; [they are context managers them selves](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement). A `closing` wrapper will just call their `close()` methods on exit.

There's no need to manually call `close()` when using cursors in a with-block. The same does not apply to connections; only the transaction is ended on exit from a with-block. This is by design, so that you can use the same connection in multiple with-blocks:

> Note that, unlike file objects or other resources, exiting the connection’s with block doesn’t close the connection but only the transaction associated with it: a connection can be used in more than a with statement and each with block is effectively wrapped in a separate transaction

You could for example wrap the connection in `closing` in an outermost with-block, and then use the same connection in inner with-blocks for transaction handling etc:

```
# This'll handle closing the connection
with closing(psycopg2.connect(...)) as conn:
    # This'll handle the transaction and closing the cursor
    with conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
        ...
```

Comment: Great answer! I really like your idea of using an outermost with-block. Although in my case I don't need to use the connection in multiple with-blocks so I just decided to close the connection in a `finally` block.